# Need help aligning dynamic td element in html form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following piece of code:

```
<tr>    
    <td style="display:none;" id="missing_person_report_label"><b>Enter image</b></td>
    <td style="display:none;" id="missing_person_report_image"><input type="file"><br/></td>
</tr>
```

These `td` elements are initially set as hidden and are only displayed when I'm selecting the "Missing Person Report" option from the dropdown menu. The Javascript function to activate these `td` elements is given as:

```
function checkForChange(that) {
    if (that.value == "missing_person_report") {
        console.log(that.value);
        console.log('person');
        document.getElementById("missing_person_report_label").style.display = "block";  
        document.getElementById("missing_person_report_image").style.display = "block";            
    }
}
```

The code is doing as intended but there is a problem with the alignment of the `tr` element. This is the screenshot of the webpage.
[image: Screenshot]

I want the `Choose file` to have the same alignment as all the above elements,i.e. I want the `Choose file` to be on the right side of the `Enter Image` label . How do I do it?

Edit: Full Code is available [here](https://github.com/Ronith12/Complaint-Registration-System/blob/master/index.html):

Edit: Those who are saying that I should assign the `style` to `tr` instead of `td`, I already tried doing this. If I do this, the webpage looks like this:[image: Screenshot2]

I want all the elements on the right to have the same alignment.

Comment: share your full html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ronith.
Actially you their CSS as block, so that's why they are on separated lines. You should set `display = "table-cell"`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>    
    <td
      id="missing_person_report_label"><b>Enter image</b></td>
    <td
      id="missing_person_report_image"><input type="file"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S.: do not pay attention that `display` is in CSS. It's just for instance. You should set it from JS code as you wish

Answer (score 1):

`display:block;` makes a html element to take the full width of it's parent. So, you made tds to block level element they took all the width available and the upper one pushed the second one below.

Solution is not to change it's default display property. However try with `inline-block` or `table-cell;` which is the default property for tds inside a table.

Comment: Adding `table-cell` instead of `block` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ronith glad this worked for you. if you have not changed the default property then you don't need the js to change.

Answer (score 0):

try this - apply display none to tr and not the td and from the function display block it again

```
<tr style="display:none;" id="missing_person_report_row">    
  <td><b>Enter image</b></td>
  <td><input type="file"><br/></td>
</tr>
```

Function

```
function checkForChange(that) {
  if (that.value == "missing_person_report") {
  console.log(that.value);
  console.log('person');
  document.getElementById("missing_person_report_row").style.display = "block";              
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of display:block in javascript. set display: inline-block in your javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("missing_person_report_label").style.display = "inline-block";  
document.getElementById("missing_person_report_image").style.display = "inline-block";
```